# Why does Windows Progress Bar always give such horrible estimates?

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows File Copy Dialog: Why is the Estimation So… BAD?](https://superuser.com/questions/43562/windows-file-copy-dialog-why-is-the-estimation-so-bad)

I realized this "bug" a long time ago, since Windows 95/98, but it still continues until today, on Windows Seven.

Today I was compressing a 1GB folder with the Windows zip(it is not a exclusive event from compression process, I already seen this before on a copy/paste of files), as shown above:

[image: compression]

(It is in Portuguese, but is the screen for the Windows progress bar showing 60 minutes of remainder time to complete the compression process)

The displayed remainder time was on 60 minutes, but the real time was less than 2 minutes.

There is any specific reason to this strange event happened? There is some way to refine or correct this kind of "bug"?