# make copy/delete dialog update for every file touched so that computer feels faster and more computery

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

back in the days of Windows XP I used to think my PC was soooooo fast because when I would copy/delete files I could see how fast the harddrive was touching the files.

In Windows 7 they replaced the old dialog with a fancier one that makes my computer feel slower and less computery.

I'd like to adjust teh cooldown on the how frequently the copy/delete info dialog gets updated [so that I can see (60 updates per second)] so that my PC will feel fast again.

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ygiTf.png

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/43562/windows-file-copy-dialog-why-is-the-estimation-so-bad The Windows copy dialog (in XP) stores the copy in memory first, and is still copying after the dialog closes.

Comment: @Rsya Studios that has little to do with my question besides "copying". I want the 'Name:' field to update on every file that gets touched.

Comment: this is a purely aesthetic change. I guess what I'm asking is: "is there a registry key I can modify that determines how regularly the File Copy/Delete dialog gets visually updated/rendered?". I want to crank it up a notch

Comment: I said it was a related question, not a duplicate of it. It was for extra information, not an attempt to solve this question.

Comment: The [SuperCopier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercopier/) plug-in for explorer may give you a more informative dialogue. SourceForge has the 32-bit executable, but the link to the web-site has 64-bit and portable versions. You can enable and disable the plug-in at will.

Comment: @AFH care to make that and the replacement, Ultracopier, an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SuperCopier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supercopier/) plug-in for explorer gives a more informative dialogue. SourceForge has the 32-bit executable, but the link to the web-site has 64-bit and portable versions. It also has an alternative skin under the name Ultracopier.

You can enable and disable the plug-in at will.